# Magento and the <video> tag (e.g. HTML5 Video with Flash Fallback)

Tags: flash, video, html, magento

Is Magento somehow unique in a way that would make the (now becoming a standard) `<video>` tag (e.g. HTML5 Video with Flash Fallback) and its related js + swf players not perform well in a Magento site?

I understand that regular html blocks can be used in Magento but I have to ask because it seems like with Magento - ya just never know.

Also, I have had a few developers tell me if I wanted to develop a store that has strong and current video features (e.g. video galleries with the latest custom players like flarevideo.com/ or mediafront.org/) that I would be better off going with Drupal (because of the existing modules drupal.org/project/mediafront and/or
drupal.org/project/flashvideo).

The problem with using Drupal is losing some of the richer e-com features of Magento.

So what's up with getting current video solutions in Magento?

any feedback much appreciated!

Comment: What is not performing well ? Is the video playing or not ? Is the fallback working or not ?

Comment: no- i dont have this functioning in Mage. I have a Flash Player that works fine but the question is about a full integration of the stated players/code. 

1. no real custom video module exists to move magneto forward with multimedia (not nearly as elegantly as this aspires to:  http://mediafront.org/drupalconsf )

2. even without a custom module or something that interfaces directly with Mage, the question is about whether there is anything in mage that would prevent using the newer but now commonplace video solutions...


bottom line is...its everywhere else...so whats up with MAGENTO!!!!!!

Comment: Magento is not a CMS (though it includes a little CMS). This could explain why there seems to be no plugin to integrate this tag yet. I think what you have to check is if Magento can allow html5 (personally I see no reason why it wouldn't).

Comment: right..as i understand the video tag can be used in html4 too. i am just astonished that given how easy it is to embed flash galleries in magento (and possibly have a rudimentary panel in admin)...that it is soo complex and difficult to use video tag...

mage developers are dropping the ball on this one...step up to the plate ala http://www.mediafront.org/drupalconsf!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this has been solved

you can:

a. host all video and player assets remotely and paste in code almost anywhere (blocks, widgets) JW Player and SlideShowPro both work on web and iOS now

b. for pure HTML5 video tag just paste in the code (all urls absolute and outside of magneto)